# Need to copy cell to another sheet and then overwrite with new value (loop)

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I need to make a VBA which copy a cell into a cell in another sheet. (Same workbook).

Afterwards i have to create a pdf (i have VBA for this).

After the pdf creation, i need do this all over automatically and i would like to have a VBA for this. Because i need to make 200 pdfs

My question is therefore:

How can i create a VBA which copy a cell from a list i sheetB to a cell in SheetA, and after the creation of the pdf, do it all over with the next cellvalue from sheetB? I guess it is something with the "looping" tool?

Answer (score 0):

A good way to create basic VBA to automate standard tasks it to record a macro while you perform the steps.  Afterwards, you can view the VBA that was generated for the macro, automate it further as necessary.  Here's some instruction and examples:

- [Getting Started with VBA in Excel 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814737(v=office.14).aspx)
- [Recording a Macro to Generate Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/recording-a-macro-to-generate-code)
- [Revising Recorded Visual Basic Macros](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/revising-recorded-visual-basic-macros)

I'm not aware of a "looping tool" but there are various ways to [loop](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/299036/how-to-loop-through-a-list-of-data-on-a-worksheet-by-using-macros-in-e) through data with Excel.

---

**Edit**: 
[Looping](https://www.google.ca/search?q=working%20with%20vba%20loops) through a list is the easy part.  For example, the following code pops up a `MsgBox` with the value of each cell in range A1 to A15:

```
Dim cel As Range
For Each cel In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A15")
    MsgBox cel.Value
Next cel
```

Get your VBA together for doing your task once, add the code to your question, and then we can stick the loop in the correct spot.

Comment: I am awere of the recording tool.

This is a very helpfull tool, but how do I after recording add the part where the macro needs to do it all over with the next value in the list in sheetB?

Comment: I have now recorded the macro for doing it once:

Sub Listing()
'
' Listing Macro
'

'
    Range("S4").Select
    Sheets("Materials list").Select
    Range("B4").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("PID Template").Select
    Range("S4").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("S7").Select
End Sub

In the end it says Range("S7").Select, but here i have pressed a button with a create pdf macro in which is located on cell S7. 

Cant i press a macrobutton in a macro?